# Gradient function that returns a list of all colors in order

Tags: python, performance

I've made this Function `gradient()` that returns a list of **rbg** of all the colors in an order.

***Issues:-***

- What should be the condition for while loop to stop the loop. Though `b == 0` in the last `elif` block works fine.
- How can I reduce the code of the function keeping the functionality the same. Like if there is any better approach to doing this.
- Also, How can I calculate the length of the `rbg_list` just with the value of `gap` parameter without running the function. *Let's say the length of the `rbg_list` will be 1529 if `gap=1` so I can iterate it with `range(1529)`.*

---

***`gradient()` function:-***

```py
def gradient(gap=1):
    r, g, b = 255, 0, 0

    if gap<=0: 
        return (r, g, b)

    rbg_list = []
    while True:
        if  r == 255 and g >= 0 and g < 255 and b == 0:           # 1
            g += gap
            if g > 255:
                g = 255

        elif r <= 255 and g == 255 and r > 0 and b == 0:          # 2
            r -= gap
            if r < 0:
                r = 0
        
        elif r == 0 and g == 255 and b < 255 and b >= 0:          # 3
            b += gap
            if b > 255:
                b = 255
        
        elif r == 0 and g <= 255 and g > 0 and b == 255:          # 4
            g -= gap
            if g < 0:
                g = 0
        
        elif r >= 0 and g == 0 and r < 255 and b == 255:          # 5
            r += gap
            if r > 255:
                r = 255
        
        elif r == 255 and g == 0 and b > 0 and b <= 255:          # 6
            b -= gap
            if b < 0:
                b = 0
                
            if b == 0: break
        
        # print(r, g, b)
        rbg_list.append((r, g, b))
    return rbg_list

print(gradient(5))
```

***Note:-*** I want the function to be compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: Is this in python 2 or python 3?

Comment: @Linny: I want it to run on both Python versions.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I rarely do python nowadays, but cleanup of the conditions would be:

```
def add(c, gap):
    return min(255, c + gap)
   
def sub(c, gap):
    return max(0, c - gap)

def gradient(gap=1):
    r, g, b = 255, 0, 0

    if gap<=0: 
        return (r, g, b)

    rbg_list = []
    while True:
        if  r == 255 and g < 255 and b == 0:         # 1
            g = add(g, gap)

        elif r > 0 and g == 255 and b == 0:          # 2
            r = sub(r, gap)
        
        elif r == 0 and g == 255 and b < 255:        # 3
            b = add(b, gap)
        
        elif r == 0 and g > 0 and b == 255:          # 4
            g = sub(g, gap)
        
        elif r < 255 and g == 0 and b == 255:        # 5
            r = add(r, gap)
        
        elif r == 255 and g == 0 and b > 0:          # 6
            b = sub(b, gap)
                
            if b == 0: break
        
        # print(r, g, b)
        rbg_list.append((r, g, b))
    return rbg_list
```

Now let me understand what happens. Let us on paper name the 3 states for a color component x (r, g or b):

```
    a = x == 0
    b = 0 < x < 255
    c = x == 255 
    
    a :   == 0
    bc :  > 0
    c :   == 255
    ab :  < 255
    
    start: c a a
    
    c   ab  a    .+.  -->>  c c a
    bc  c   a    -..  -->>  a c a
    a   c   ab   ..+  -->>  a c c
    a   bc  c    .-.  -->>  a a c
    ab  a   c    +..  -->>  c a c
    c   a   bc   ..-  -->>  c a a
```

A very limited kind of gradient, restricted to one color component.
This  could be written as 6 loops:

```
        while g < 255:         # 1
            g += gap
            rbg_list.append((r, g, b))

        g = 255
        rbg_list.append((r, g, b))
            
        while r > 0:           # 2
            r -= gap
            
        r = 0
        rbg_list.append((r, g, b))

        ...
```

However you have just increasing from 0 by `gap`, and decreasing from 255 by `gap`.
These would give two component value arrays which can then be used with the two other components 0 or 255. That should be exploitable in Python.

You might also calculate how many `gap` steps are needed for 255, times 6, and have a function that gives for the ith step the (r, g, b). **That would be the simplest.**

I admit I might be mistaken in what gradient calculation you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation, I really like how you simplify the function with `add` and `sub` functions. I've figured a calculation to find the total iterations according to the value given to `gap` by this `len([c for c in range(0, 255, gap)])*6-1`, this gives me the accurate value and also I've tested it by comparing to the length of the list with different `gap` values, but I'm not sure if this is how it should be calculated.

Comment: You forget to return the values of functions `add` and `sub`.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenRauch corrected that. If you write out the loop, add/siub are not needed too, only for the <= 0, >= 255 value one, which then becomes an assignment = 0, resp. = 255. The total number of iterations could also be done with approx. (255/gap) * 6 with careful rounding. Maybe faster then range.